# Spark DataGrid alternative Row Color Changes

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, flex-spark

How to Set alternat Row Color In Flex 4.5 MobileApplication For Spark Data Grid. The Main Problem Of SparkDataGrid in Mobile Application not Allowed  to Add Skin.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [alternatingRowColors style](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html#commonstyleSummary).  To quote the docs:

> Type: Array Format: Color CSS Inheritance: no Theme: spark
>
> Used to initialize the DataGrid's rowBackground skin part. If the
>   alternatingRowColors style is specified, then use the
>   alternatingRowColorsBackground skin part as the value of the
>   rowBackground skin part. The alternating colors for the grid rows are
>   defined by successive entries in the Array value of this style.
>
> If you want to change how this style is rendered, replace the
>   alternatingRowColorsBackground skin part in the DataGridSkin class. If
>   you want to specify the background for each row, then initialize the
>   rowBackground skin part directly.
>
> The default value is undefined.

Comment: Thanks For your Answer Sir , But The Main Problem SparkDatagrid Is Not Allowed A Skin Property In mobile Applicaton.

Comment: That problem has nothing to do with the original question I answered.  If you want the Spark DataGrid to work in a mobile app you'll have to create your own mobile skin for it. That isn't hard, but is most likely going to be tedious. It is possible you'll have to extend the DataGrid to accept touch inputs instead of mouse input. Based on my past experience--with the DropDownList/ComboBox; I'd plan a month for this (minimum).  If you have a budget for converting the Spark DataGrid to mobile, ping me privately ( https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ContactForm) and we'll work something out.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following style to your application:

```
s|DataGrid
{
    alternatingRowColors:#FFFFFF,#CCCCCC;
}
```

This will make the odd rows white and the even rows gray. Now, I have not tested this using Mobile so it may or may not work. Please follow up with results.

-Vic